# Vlookup VBA taking huge time and returning wrong values

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a vlookup formula in VBA

```
.Range("BO2:BO" & NewLastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(BN2,'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!$BL$2:$BM$" & OldLastRow & ",2,0)"
```

As this a case of Exact match, it is taking huge time. But when i change it to approx match ,it is returning wrong values. Basically i want to vlookup dates from other worksheet.

Comment: how are you calculating `NewLastRow` and `OldLastRow`?

Comment: How many rows do you have? And how many times are you writing the formula? E.g. what are the values of `NewLastRow` and `OldLastRow`?

Comment: I have more than 500K rows..That's why it is taking time.

Comment: why don't you use `Find` and `FindNext` instead?